# SlideView Crashes the Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT)**

I added **SlideView Library** to it. Added three grids to slideview. It works **fine and awsome.** 
https://slideview.codeplex.com

Now the problem lies in **navigation**. I added a buton in slideview and Whenever I click on it to navigate to another page of app, it **crashes**.

```
<controls:SlideView>

    <Grid Background="Teal"
            Width="400">
                    <Button Click="Button_Click">Goto all questions test </Button>
</Grid>

    <Grid Background="Tomato" />

    <Grid Background="LightYellow" />

    <Grid Background="YellowGreen"
            Width="400"/>

</controls:SlideView>






 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MedicalUserQuestionAnswerFeedPage));
    }
```

I tried to debug every line but Visual studio is not catching the exception.

Comment: Have you tried removing the SlideView to see if it crashes? Maybe something is wrong on the page you're navigating to? Do you get an exception? What kind of exception?

Comment: On removing SlideView, everything is normal.  They have actually showed an example on website but If I use SlideView like that it will remain n every page in my app. I just want SlideView on one page. I am not getting any exception. Just on clicking the button inside SlideView to navigate to another page crahes the app and VisualStudio debugging stops. It is not catching any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPage)));
```

I had the same problem and this fixed it. I haven't yet found the underlying cause, but I plan to investigate as this is pretty annoying